# How to register csv data as contentful entry

Tags: contentful

I want to post csv data which is wordpress _post data to contentful content.

this is model at contentful.

[image]

maybe this is SDK api which can provide function of posting.

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/cli/import-and-export/

but don't know how to use it.

please help me.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to import CSV into Contentful? How does it relate to Gatsby (question tag)? What did you try?

Comment: thank you for relpy! I use gatsby + contentful to build my site. I used wordpress before. I have about 100 articles and want to upload that to contentful.

Comment: this question is too vague and needs more clarification. Specifically which step are you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contentful import and export tools are command line libraries that consume Contentufl Management API, this is the API in charge up writes to a Contentful space.

Remembering [Contentful concepts](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/), in order to have data stored in entries, you need to have a Content Model which defines schema.

So with Contentful export/import you can batch dump or migrate Content Model, Entries or Assets.

As you're mentioning that you come from a Wordpress site, I may recommend taking a look at this [migration guide](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2015/03/09/exporting-content-from-wordpress-drupal-or-elsewhere-and-importing-in-contentful/).

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful advice. Once I made the model locally, I pasted all the text from the WordPress article into it and imported it, and it worked.

Comment: Happy to help @KATUO 

Feel free to reach out if you need anything